# Receive 403 access denied error using the nsis nsisdl

Tags: nsis

In my NSIS script, I am attempting to download a file from our web server using the following command:

NSISdl::download /NOIEPROXY http://ntcpc-004158:8080 MCRInstaller.exe

I get a HTTP 403 access denied error.  I am sure that server address is correct and the file is on the server.

I've researched this issue and heard that the inetc plug-in is beter.  I wrote a test script and got an error that the inetc::get command was not recognized.

I didn't find that many details on how to install a plug-in except for any dll files go in the plugins subfolder beneath the NSIS installation folder.  Any nsh files go in the include subfolder beneath the NSIS installation folder.  However, I did not see any nsh files in the inetc zip file.

Excuse me if my issue seems like a dumb quesiton.  I have been using NSIS for a few months.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

NSISdl uses basic sockets and custom HTTP handling, INetC uses the same engine as Internet Explorer.

To install a plugin you place the .dll file in the plugins directory or use `!addplugindir` in your script. Not all plugins have a .nsh file, if they don't it means that you use the `dll::function` plugin syntax to call the plugin directly...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I can call the inetc::get command now.  However, this call still fails to retreive the file.  I have used the following two calls:

Comment: inetc::get /caption "MCR Installer" /popup "" "http://ntcpc-004158:8080/file_name" "$EXEDIR\file_name" /END   inetc::get /silent "http://ntcpc-004158:8080/To_Do_List.txt" "$EXEDIR\To_Do_List" /end  Depending on the file_name I use, I get a "file open" error or "file not found" error?  I am sure that the file_name I am using is on the url.  What is the reason for the failure?  A network security issue or something else.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why is there a ; at the end of the url? Did you try a "normal" url on the public internet?

Comment: I am able to download a web page from a normal url using the following command: inetc::get /silent "http://www.ndwarlords.freeserve.co.uk/microancient1.htm" "$EXEDIR\data.txt" /end Thank you for your reply.  Note: for some reason, a semicolon is being added between the url and EXEDIR statement when I save my edit.